# Who gets the broccoli stick? Random walk in a circle.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, random-walk

Suppose we have $n+1$ people in a circle ${0,1,2,3....n}$, we pass around a broccoli stick. The person $k$ has probability $p$ to pass the stick to $k+1$ and probability $q = 1-p$ to pass it to the $k-1$ person. And $p>0.5>q$.

NOTE: THIS IS NOT A SYMMETRIC WALK!

One wins if he is the last person remaining that has not touched the stick.

Where should a person situate to get the best possibility of winning?

I Want to calculate P(person i-1) gets the stick, passes it to i+1 without going through i. And P(person i+1) gets stick, passes it to i-1 without going through i, then condition.

Comment: how does one win

Comment: I tried to polish a little the question, but the last paragraph is hard to understand.

Comment: No it is not. This walk is Not Symmetric! I want to know the general asymmetric answer!

Comment: @user270133 The answer of that question is for the general asymmetric case, I think, check it.

Comment: @leonbloy where can i find that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1441461/312