# The last visit chance of a biased random walk on a circle

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

it is well-known that:

> For a balanced random walk on a circle with n sites, except for the start point A, all the other points share the same probability: 1/(n-1), to be the last visited site.

Now I'm wondering if I change the scenario from balanced to a biased case?

Say for all sites, the probability of going clockwise is p, counter-clockwise is (1-p).

Can we build a martingale to solve this problem?

---

**Edit:** Consider the following 2 different scenarios.

1. 100 people sitting around a big table. Everyone wants to try an amazing sauce. Starting from you, everyone will pass the sauce bottle to the left or right next seat with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

> What is the probability that the person next to you, on your left becomes the last  one to receive the sauce?

> How about the person on you right (next to you)?

> How about the person at any chosen seat?

2. The same setup and the same questions, but now everyone will pass the bottle to the left with probability p and to the right with probability (1-p).

---

Many thanks to @user51547! The answer is here:

[Martingale solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432301/last-vertex-visited-by-the-symmetric-random-walk-on-a-discrete-circle)

The idea is the same to a biased Gambler's Ruin.

The only difference is that, in classical Gambler's Ruin, one only needs to consider one direction. Here we need to consider from 2 directions. See the link for detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you explain what are transition probabilities and what is actually the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @StasVolkov Sorry for the confusion previously. I edited the question a bit. Appreciate it!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432301/last-vertex-visited-by-the-symmetric-random-walk-on-a-discrete-circle