# A random walk on a circle with $n$ points. What is the probability that the walk will end at point $i$ ? ($0 \le i \le n-1$)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk

$n>1$ points numbered $0,1,2,...,n-1$ are placed on a circle.

A random walker starts his journey at point $0$ and at each step, he steps randomly on the circle to one of the two closest points.

For $0 \le i \le n-1$, we'll say that $p_i$ is the probability that the moment this man reaches the point $i$, he already visited the rest of the points. Meaning, he traveled all rest the points already and now he finaly visited the point $i$ for the first time. And that's where his journey comes to an end.

So, what is $p_i$ ?

The answer is:

$$p_i =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n-1},  & \text{for $i\neq0$} \\
0, & \text{for $i=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

And i don't get it! Does it means that $p_i$ is uniformly distributed or something?

The way i see it, the point $i$ may never even get reach! If some point, let's say point $2$, is placed far from everyone, why would this man reach it at at? he'll go around in the same routine 'till infinity and never decide to go to $2$.

I believe i didn't get the question right. Or maybe i'm wrong with my thinking. I just hope i translated this question correctly so you can help me understand what is going on here or solve this.

Comment: The thing is, these routines where he never reaches 2 after a large number of steps have very low probability.

Comment: Also I believe the beginning of Fnacool's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273163/simple-random-walk-on-cycle-graph-ending-on-specific-vertex-after-cover-time/4274257#4274257 should help you in reaching the formula for $p_i$.

Comment: Yes it means $p_i$ is uniform (and that the starting point is visited before the first step - you would get a different answer otherwise, for example consider $n=2$ or $3$).  The probability of not visiting all the points is $0$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you are missing the part that it is on a circle.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Oops. Thanks...